# Grouping Laravel controllers in folders

Tags: php, laravel

To organize my controllers, I would like to sort them in folders. For example, I have an admin panel that utilizes many controllers that I don't want mixed up with the other controllers. I moved those controllers in a folder in my /controllers directory.

So my structure looks like this:

```
controllers /
    BaseController.php
    HomeController.php

    admin /    
       AdminController.php
```

Now my admin controller looks like this:

```
namespace Admin;

class AdminController extends \BaseController {

    public function getHome() {

        return \View::make('admin.home');

    }

}
```

Then I can do a grouped route for my admin panel:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin'], function() {

    Route::get('admin', ['as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'AdminController@getHome']);

});
```

**There's absolutely nothing wrong with this however**, I find it a nuisance having to namespace every class in these controllers using `\`. Is there I way I can eliminate the use of having to namespace every class in these controllers under admin? For example, I don't want to type `\View::make()`, I want to have `View::make()`.

Comment: The only way around this is to have `use View;` at the top of the PHP file, after the `namespace` declaration (which is, in effect, saying to PHP 'get View from the global namespace and import it here for me to use as if relative').

Comment: So for every class I need to reference it with use?

Comment: There's no way I can use them all in one?

Comment: If you're inside a namespace you're basically alienating yourself from the global namespace, so you need to use `use` (or `\` as you know) in every namespaced class and for everything you want to import from the global namespace. That is the (rather annoying) compromise. Luckily things like global functions work because PHP tries the function in the current namespace, and then traces backwards through namespaces till it finds a function matching the name you use. But it does not do this with classes.

Comment: Then I'm guessing the easiest way would be just prefixing the classes with the namespace.

Comment: Of course, if you don't want to use namespaces you don't have to - you can still group by folders and have Composer autodetect your classes with the `classmap` autoload option. They will all be in the global namespace, so you can't have two with the same name, but it may help you out for now.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you want your controller classes to still be in the global namespace but want the ability to organize them into folders.

If you look in your `composer.json`, you'll see that the default controllers folder is autoloaded by "classmap" to the folder directly. So you may add additional folders to the list. Like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/controllers/admin", <-- additional folders
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
    ]
},
```

Notice that I added `"app/controllers/admin"` into the `classmap` array. You can add as many as you want. Then do a `composer dump-autoload`.

Another way of doing the same approach is to modify your `app/start/global.php`:

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(

    app_path().'/commands',
    app_path().'/controllers',
    app_path().'/controllers/admin', // additional folders
    app_path().'/models',
    app_path().'/helpers',
    app_path().'/database/seeds',

));
```

AFAIK, this gives the same effect as modifying `composer.json` file, with exception that you do not need to do any `composer` commands after adding a new path.

---

Note that the whole answer above will work well if you do not expect your code to grow considerably larger. Imagine having to maintain tens of controller folders this way, also the risk of class names clashing.