# Separate folders for controller

Tags: php, laravel

I want to separate my controllers into two different folders BackEnd and FrontEnd, but when I do it shows an error:
 **`Class App\Http\Controllers\CredentialsController` does not exist**. This credentialscontroller is inside BackEnd folder so I changed the namespace to **`namespace App\Http\Controllers\BackEnd;`** and also added **`use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;`** so that it still extends the base controller in the CredentialsController then I used composer dump-autoload but it's still not working. It shows the same error. Also I have tried adding this to my composer.json just to check if it works and it still throws the same error.

```
 "autoload": {
          "files": [
           "App\Http\Controllers\BackEnd\CredentialsController.php"
         ]
     },
```

All I want to do is separate my controllers for BackEnd and FrontEnd.

Comment: You probably still have to adjust the namespace where you use the controller. For example in a route: `Route::resource('credentials', 'BackEnd\CredentialsController');`

Comment: using laravel 4 or 5?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grouping Laravel controllers in folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039490/grouping-laravel-controllers-in-folders)

Comment: I have found the solution thanks  lukasgeiter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably still have to adjust the namespace where you actually use the controller.

For example in a route:

```
Route::resource('credentials', 'BackEnd\CredentialsController');
```

Comment: I agree with @limonte

Answer (score 0):

You must include Namespace in route, 
namespace are mapped as folder path
Route::resource('credentials', 'BackEnd\CredentialsController');